# Dynamically-inserted content creates odd margin

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a page that loads a list of values into a listbox. The values are retrieved from a database when the page loads, and the list is constructed using PHP.

After the page loads, the user can enter a new value and add it to the list via jQuery. The new list item is constructed as a DOM tree using jQuery, but it is identical in every way to the ones generated by PHP. I compared the two using the Chrome dev tools, and they are the same.

Anyway, this all works fine, except that one of the spans in the jQuery-inserted ones have a slightly different position.

[image: An example]

*(the orange dotted lines are added for visual reference; they are `outline` values, so they don't affect the positioning of any of the elements)*

I use the same classes for both, and I even checked the computed styles with Chrome. The list items inserted by PHP and the ones inserted by jQuery have exactly the same styles. And yet Smith Bob, the one inserted via jQuery, is not lining up.

What could be causing this?

I haven't posted any CSS because there is quite a lot, and I'm not sure how much help it would be. Since I've looked at each individual computed value and they are all identical, I'm thinking it may not be a CSS problem.

**EDIT:** *[Removed test URL, as it resided on a server I don't control, and no longer seems necessary given the question has been answered]*

The red 追加 buttons in the left-hand list should add items to the right-hand list, but they will appear not to line up, just like the image above.

Comment: ah, good idea! sorry... I'll upload it now.

Comment: I see them aligned with chromium

Comment: I'm testing in Chrome and Safari on Mac OS X (Japanese version), and they both show the odd alignment issue. I'd like to test on a Windows machine, but I don't have access to one for a few more hours. Maybe it is a browser/OS issue...?

Comment: @david, I'm testing on win7, firefox and chrome. they both have that strange space. If you delete the bullet spans in the dev tools, the spaces are equal. Haven't figured out why... yet.

Comment: Hmm... I originally thought jQuery was not putting enough space in, but now I think the PHP is inserting too much. Examining the margins seems to indicate that the jQuery ones line up, but the PHP ones don't. Putting that together with what you said, maybe it's a hidden char in or around the bullet tag?

Comment: Found it! i'll post it in an answer. just a sec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With inline elements, it is possible you see the whitespace in your html code.
you can test this. Create an unorderd list en make the li's inline (give them a BG color). Can you see the space? Now make them float-> boom, space is gone.

In your PHP code, the html is nicely formatted. your spans are inline elements, thus they show the (white)space. The HTML you insert via javascript isn't formatted, but concattenated with no spaces in between, so there is no whitespace to show.

So float your spans and your problem is fixed.

Comment: Aw, are you serious? If that's what this is, I really need to slap myself... Gonna try it out now.

Comment: that's it. 
happy slapping ;-)

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you kindly, Sir and/or Madam. -sigh- Why is it always something stupidly basic?

Comment: Now I have my own proof *and* the fiddle proof! Double the proof, double the shame... cheers ;-)

Comment: Don't beat yourself up over it. It happens to all of us every now and again. cheers!

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, I think there's a problem not with the user-inserted items, but rather with the ones that are inserted at page-load.

When I start the page in an english version of Chrome, the 'Currently Active Items' list is all screwed-up. Removing each of the items, before adding them again by clicking button with the red text makes the list look okay. It also makes the mouse hovering work correctly again, since each item exists on a single row, rather than 2 - 1 of which overlaps an adjacent element.

This is what I'm seeing. Left image is immediately after the page has loaded, right image has shows the list after clearing and re-populating.

[image]

Code added for completeness - promised in comment below. If it helps someone else, great!

```
<script>
<?php
    printf("var apartmentComplexes = { mArray : %s };", json_encode($apartmentComplexes));
?>

// an exerpt of what above statement produces
var apartmentComplexes = { mArray : [{"name":"Aria","description":"Uma das<br> mais exclusivas propostas de Porto ......

function myOnLoad()
{
    var numComplexes = apartmentComplexes.mArray.length;

    // do some other stuff with the apartmentComplexes object


    setPageApartmentComplex(0);
}

</script>
```

Comment: Okay, so that niggling suspicion I was beginning to have appears to be correct. Thanks for the screenshots! I'll have to pick apart the PHP and see if there are any unwanted guests there....

Comment: No worries, I don't use jQuery, so I cant suggest code - however I'd be inclined to use jQuery to populate the table after the page loads. That way you'll be using a single mechanism to insert the items. The key difference being that this mechanism will be started via code instead of a user-interaction event. :shrugs:

Comment: You're right. Ordinarily I wouldn't be using two methods to do the same thing like this. But the db values are retrieved via PHP, so it is easier to use PHP to make the initial list. On the flipside, I toyed with the idea of ajaxing the user-created list items, but it seemed like unnecessary overhead. Plus it now appears that would only compound the problem, since the PHP code is the problem to begin with. Ah well. Only an hour to go before I can test on an English machine, so I'll give that a try and report back later....

Comment: Well, this is me reporting back later to say I'm not gonna be reporting back later :-) Thanks for your help though, it made me think outside the box, which is never a bad thing.

Comment: Whenever I want to do something like that, I create the array in php then spit-it-out into a json string that I echo as a javascript array. You already know which items will appear in the left-hand list, you also know which items should already be in the right list. So, what I'd do was create an array of the indices of the items that need adding. I'd output it as a json string. I'll update my answer to include an exerpt of code I have in use at the moment. In any case, guess the english version is only 3/4 of an hour away now. Cheers. Hehe - just saw you comment - nice first sentence. hehe!

Comment: Hey, that's not a bad idea. I'll look into it, might save me some time. Cheers!